# Whether logbase2^k(n) is O(Big O) , o(Small o) , BigOmega, small omega or Theta of n^e

Tags: algorithm, wolframalpha

Here k>=1 and e >0. This is a homework question and from what i understood is since n^e is a polynomial function it will always grow faster that log^k(n)(log is to the base 2) so ,

```
log^k(n) = o (n^e)
```

But when i try to plot the graph at [www.wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com) to confirm my understanding it does not give me the clear picture. Can anyone tell me if there is a better way to analyse this.

Comment: What are `k` and `e` ? Just constants?

Comment: All you need for this is l'Hospitals rule and the fact that if lim n->infty f(n)/g(n) < infty, then f = O(g), and if it's even 0, then f = o(g). Remember that the derivative of log^k(n) is k*log^(k-1)(n)*(1/n). If k is real, just round up and you'll get an upper bound on the limit since log(n) > 1 for almost all n.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on http://cs.stackexchange.com?